# How exactly is kinetic energy transferred between two moving objects when a force is applied?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation

I have a question about how kinetic energy is transferred between two objects when a force is applied between them.
It sounds simple but when thinking about "what really happens" I have some questions. I also checked other entries but couldn't find a detailed explanation.

I will use a basic example, the elastic collision.

Let's say I have two objects with the same mass, a spring (considered with no mass) is attached to the first object.

t=1: Object 1 accelerated from 0m/s to 10m/s. Object 2 is not moving.

t=2: Object 1 has reached object 2 and the spring between them is compressed. Object 1 and object 2 are now both moving with 5m/s. 1/4 of the initial kinetic energy is stored in each object, 1/2 in the compression of the spring.

t=3: While the spring expands to its original state, object 1 is decelerated until it reaches 0m/s, object 2 is accelerated until it reaches 10m/s.

For the numbers, momentum and energy conservation everything is fine. Momentum and energy has not changed. At t=2 a part of the energy is stored in the compressed spring.

**Where I have some questions:**
From t=2, the spring decelerates object 1. The kinetic energy from object 1 is transferred to object 2.

What is the mechanism how the energy "flows" through the spring from object 1 to object 2?
I have trouble seeing how the object that is pushed back can propagate its energy.

I can imagine that if I would stop object 2 for a short time, the spring will be compressed further by object 1 (kinetic energy is converted). If I then stop object 1 for a short time the spring will expand and thus accelerate object 2.

But as the transition happens continuously, I wonder how this mechanism works in detail. As long as object 1 is faster than object 2 it is clear to me, as object 1 is still compressing the spring. **I have trouble to imagine what happens exactly when object 1 is slower than object 2 but it still passes on the momentum and energy.**

Is there any model what happens in detail?
Some backgrounds would be highly appreciated. It's one of the questions where I can observe and calculate the behaviour, but would like to have more explanation.

Comment: It all boils down to the electromagnetic force.

Comment: The way objects exchange energy is by interacting through forces. You can imagine the spring as a conservative force between the two objects. If the spring is compressed, then the objects repel each other, and vice versa. This results in changes in energy and momentum for the individual objects as given by newton's laws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we often talk about energy "flowing" as if it was some sort of fluid, and sometimes it is useful to think of it that way, this can also lead to error.  Energy isn't a material, it isn't a fluid, it doesn't really "flow".  It is a calculated quantity.  Your description actually does a very good job of explaining why the energy is transferred from one object to the other, but you could make it clearer by talking about work done.

I'll introduce some more times between your times 1, 2, 3.  So

t = 1.5: the spring has just made contact with object 2, but isn't yet compressed.

t = 2.5: the spring is just about to leave contact with object 2, and is again uncompressed.

From t =1.5 to t = 2.5 think about work done.

The spring exerts a force on object 1 opposite to the direction of motion, so it is doing negative work.  So object 1 is losing energy.

The spring exerts a force on object 2 in the direction of motion, so it is doing positive work.  So object 2 is gaining energy.

Object 1 exerts a force in the direction of motion on the spring (so, doing positive work on the spring), while object 2 exerts a force opposite the direction of motion on the spring (so, it does negative work on the spring).  But overall the sum of these is positive work on the spring from t = 1.5 to t = 2, and negative work on the spring from t = 2 to t = 2.5.  It takes some harder thought and likely calculation to see why this is so, but we see the outcome of it as the spring compresses from t = 1.5 to 2 (gaining energy) then relaxes from t = 2 to 2.5 (losing energy).  Technically here we should talk about the motion of the *points of contact* between the objects and the springs, but in this case it makes no difference since everything is moving in the same direction.

My points are really this:

1. Thinking of the energy "flowing" from object 1 to object 2 likely doesn't help you conceptualize what is going on here.  It can be a nice conceptual picture sometimes, but it isn't "real".
2. Thinking about the directions of forces compared to the directions of motion tells you all about the signs of work on each object.  That shows you a reason for the transfers of energy between the various times.

The thing that isn't "obvious" without more thought is how to see that the spring must gain energy from t = 1.5 to 2 and lose it from 2 to 2.5.  One way to see it is a more advanced topic: look into how you split the system's kinetic energy up into two parts which we call the "centre of mass kinetic energy" and the "convertible kinetic energy".  The centre of mass kinetic energy can't change.  At t = 2 the system's convertible kinetic is momentarily zero.  That tells us the system's potential energy must be a maximum at that moment.  I'd suggest the intro. physics textbook Principles and Practices of Physics, by Eric Mazur, to see a fairly understandable explanation of this.  Happy reading!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think where I struggle is that at the same time the spring is gaining potential energy but also losing it. Gaining it because for object 1 the force and speed at the contact point of the spring are positive, but also losing it because for the contact point at object 2 force is negative and speed still positive. Because of the different speeds of the objects between t=2.0 and 2.5 it means the potential energy is reduced, yet object 1 still applies a force on the spring. I'll try to get some background about the centre of mass kinetic energy you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way to think about this, which may be helpful.

Besides the spring between them, the colliding objects are themselves elastic- in addition to possessing mass. When acted upon by external forces, those objects *deform* and while doing so convert kinetic energy into potential energy (i.e., elastic deformation).

Knowing the deformation of an ideal sphere under the influence of point forces then allows the integration of deflection through distance to yield the energy storage.

The key point here in visualizing the energy flow during an elastic collision is to realize that the collision is not instantaneous and that the colliding objects undergo measurable elastic deformation within the duration of the collision.